# How to send image (image url),video chat App Messages using XMPPFramework iOS

Tags: ios, xmpp, chat

I'm sending only text, but I don't know how to send image/url, videos and
integrate that in the chat application in iOS using XMPP.

Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

Please note that you should

- Provide what you have done so far.
- Search for answers first.

Please check existing answers

- [question 1](https://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjW5dWlgL_QAhUFzxQKHYd_BDUQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F33476225%2Fhow-to-send-image-in-somessaging-xmpp-framework&usg=AFQjCNGAoqfvpEyXav7J_2fEPTCsvy5ong&sig2=SqQb23Q4zftggAFRWPii3A&bvm=bv.139782543,d.d24)
- [question 2](https://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjW5dWlgL_QAhUFzxQKHYd_BDUQFggkMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F32946115%2Fhow-to-send-image-in-chat-usig-xmpp-framework&usg=AFQjCNHd1sUFFDBXrmpFCMETON4oiSZGsg&sig2=SJ9FRCmMW_F2ofh7LVdi6Q&bvm=bv.139782543,d.d24)
- [question 3](https://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjW5dWlgL_QAhUFzxQKHYd_BDUQFgg9MAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F18327203%2Fxmppframework-how-to-transfer-image-from-one-device-to-another&usg=AFQjCNGpqvpx2buiKObjTdnTkQlxZ5wz5A&sig2=RQzrFLSraeKm14QqqrSd2w&bvm=bv.139782543,d.d24)
- [question 4](https://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjW5dWlgL_QAhUFzxQKHYd_BDUQFghGMAU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F4524475%2Fsending-image-using-xmpp-framework-on-iphone&usg=AFQjCNHhZznzCKPmaZgOnxP9iLqXTe_NPg&sig2=H2TsBvZKl-7YFnzi5-hXVw&bvm=bv.139782543,d.d24)

There are two basic approaches to send media data

- inband (message with attachment - refer to existing answers)
- out-of-band (upload media file to server and send URL in message)

Sending inband data should only be used for small media data. I recommend to use the out-of-band approach.

Out-of-band solutions supported by XMPPFramework

- [XEP-0065](https://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjZxL6hhb_QAhUJOhQKHStMDaYQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fxmpp.org%2Fextensions%2Fxep-0065.html&usg=AFQjCNEl-h-HnfmVRSvnbxZ7HHJjZdUzhA&sig2=u2UlQhslV8EtbEGp_yHAmg&bvm=bv.139782543,d.d24)
- [XEP-0096](https://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwi0icvKhb_QAhVBbxQKHZuqBh0QFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fxmpp.org%2Fextensions%2Fxep-0096.html&usg=AFQjCNGqZzwSj0fH8TM_kGxqkyGjRWXGOw&sig2=2frsMnfYPaTzd3Rt0lYxjQ&bvm=bv.139782543,d.d24)
- Your own XMPP extension

You are the most flexible when you use your own extension, but a standard XMPP client will not understand this. If you implement your own clients the I recommend this approach as follows.

**Send media message**

1. Upload media file to server.
2. Send message with content attribute and out

**Receive media message**

1. Parse message received and detect content type and out-of-band file name
2. Download media file from server.
3. Delete media file from server.

**Example for your own XMPP message extension**

```
<message from=... to=... id=... type=chat>
  <body></body>
  <myapp xmlns=mycompany:myapp content=image>
    <out_of_band_file>myuniquefilename.jpg</out_of_band_file>
  </myapp>
</message>
```

This way you may define your own content types like image, video, audio.